# Why is following the standard considered to produce unreadable code or to be impossible?

Tags: c++, c

I was reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025494/obfuscating-c-c-code

The question is:

> What tools are available to obfuscate C/C++ code....

An answer which had a bounty awarded to it says:

> Follow the Standard insanely.
>
> That'll be enough :)

I don't understand why people say following the standard would produce unreadable code or is impossible. Can someone explain what people mean in that post ? I'm a beginner programmer (in C / C++)

Comment: It's supposed to be a joke - see the smiley at the end? And that's also probably the reason why the author marked it *community wiki*.

Comment: @Praetorian Good answer.I'll give you a C++ for your answer.

Comment: See - those are the kind of cryptic statements which are not understandable by idiots with no sense of humour like me. :) Where I come from getting a C means you have to repeat the course.....

Comment: The "truth" behind the joke is that some constructs that are popular amongst amateur coders actually violate the C standard; and converting the "working" program to be standard-conforming can be tedious if you are not familiar with what's standard and what isn't. For example, using `int` and `foo *` interchangeably.

Comment: One example that comes to mind; `char ch = getchar();` is allowed to raise a signal (out-of-range assignment to a signed integral type) , but it'd be a pretty unpopular compiler that did actually do that.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Of course, narrowing the result of `getchar` to `char` is almost certainly a mistake, as far as portable code is concerned; if `char` is unsigned, you'll silently fail to catch `EOF`. The raising of a signal would actually be pretty nice—giving us at least a _runtime_ notification of our error—if that implementation option actually applied to the right signedness!